# BASH if then else with quoted text

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a short script that checks for verizon fios availability by zip code from a list of 5 digit us zip codes.

The basis of this I have working but comparing the recived output from curl to the expected output in the if statements isn't working.

I know there is a better & cleaner way to do this however I'm really interested in what is wrong with this method. I think it's something to do with the quotes getting jumbled up.

Let me know what you guys think. I originally thought this would be a quick little script. ha. Thanks for the help

Here is what I have so far:

```
    #!/bin/bash

Avail='<link rel="canonical" href="http://fios.verizon.com/fios-plans.html#availability-msg" />'
NotAvail='<link rel="canonical" href="http://fios.verizon.com/order-now.html#availability-msg" />'

while read zip; do
    chk=`curl -s -d "ref=GIa6uiuwP81j047HjKMHOwEyW4QJTYjG&PageID=page9765&AvailabilityZipCode=$zip" http://fios.verizon.com/availability_post4.php --Location | grep "availability-msg"`
#echo $chk

  if [ "$chk" = "$Avail" ]
  then
    fios=1
  elif [ "$chk" = "$NotAvail" ]
  then
    fios=0
  else
    fios=err
  fi

echo "$zip | $fios"

done < zipcodes.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a bash problem? Did you check what you receive actually with your curl command? Maybe the page has changed. I couldn’t find neither the value of `$Avail` nor of `$NotAvail` in the result.

Comment: I can confirm that @erik is correct in that `$Avail` and `$NotAvail` do not show in the output. The page is probably very dynamic given that `ref` parameter. Otherwise your script seems to curl and pull zipcodes correctly.

Comment: I $Avail and $NotAvail are variables that are set on the first few lines. that part is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the line read from `curl` ends in CR/LF. `grep` will take the `LF` as a line-end, and leave the `CR` in the line, where it will not match either of your patterns.  (Other whitespace issues could also cause a similarly invisible mismatch, but stray CR's are very common since HTTP insists on them.)

The easiest solution is to use a less specific match, like a glob or regex; these are both available with bash's `[[` (rather than `[`) command.

Eg.:

```
if [[ $chk =~ /fios-plans\.html ]]; then
```

will do a substring comparison

Comment: Thank you. I had thought of spaces and CR/LF but everything you're saying makes sense. I did end up doing something similar using cut. Can you further explain the =~ operator? Thanks again.

Comment: @user3381043: `=~` matches the string on the left-hand side with the (posix extended) regular expression on the right-hand side. See the description of `[[...]]` in this section of the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

Comment: If anyone is looking for a verizon fios map in google earth, I got it done and is posted here: http://thestevenexperience.com/2014/03/12/verizon-fios-availability-map-by-u-s-zipcode

Thanks again for the help.